# Removing locale parameter from url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, subdomain, locale, refinerycms

I'm having to use rails url helpers, rather than path helpers (in some cases) as I'm working with an app that uses subdomains, so am having to pass the domain option as a parameter.

However this is causing the links to render as:

`http://sub.domain.dev/the-page?locale=en`

I've tried using variations of the following in the application controller, to no avail:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => :en }
end
```

How do I remove that locale parameter?

I'm using RefineryCMS.

Answer (score 5):

Odd, but for anyone in my situation:

When using RefineryCMS with engine, even though locale is not being used, and other engines produce the expected urls, the fix was to set:

```
# config/initializers/refinery/i18n.rb
Refinery::I18n.configure do |config|
  config.enabled = false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For refinerycms-i18n ~> 4.0:

```
# config/initializers/refinery/i18n.rb

Refinery::I18n.configure do |config|
  config.url_filter_enabled = false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using locale I recommend the following:

In your routes.rb:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|br/ do
  resources :the-pages
end
```

In your application controller:

```
before_filter :set_locale
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale]
end

def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

In this way, your urls will become:

```
http://sub.domain.dev/en/the-page
http://sub.domain.dev/pt/the-page
```

**EDIT** - if you don't want any locale, you need to remove it from your application controller:

```
#remove the below
def default_url_options(options={})
 { :locale => :en }
end
```

Also, make sure you don't have any locale in your routes.rb

Comment: Thanks, I currently don't need / want to use locale in any way - it's English only at the moment, and I would like to remove that parameter altogether and have nice clean urls...

Comment: than you just need to remove it from your application controller. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I only added that to try and remove / alter it in some way. It looks like its happening with path helpers too - its when I'm using `main_app.some_route_for(object)` for views in an engine

Comment: well, the locale is coming from somewhere... check your routes.rb, application controller, application helper... but I believe it is set in your routes.rb. You can also search for the word locale in your code to find out where it has been set.