# Remove automated ?locale=en in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, globalize

Every URL generated in my Rails app has ?locale=en appended to it. I don't understand it and I don't want it. How can I remove it?

I do not set "default_url_options" in application_controller.rb

Here is the content of my config/application.rb

```
config.i18n.available_locales = %i[en es]
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

My Setup:
- Rails 6.0.2.2
- Ruby 2.7.0
- Globalize gem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853043/4758119

Comment: I have fixed it. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9828215) really helped.